# IP*Works! or Indy - which is more stable as FTP client/server architecture?

Tags: delphi, indy

I'm really wondering which is more stable in building FTP client/server architecture.

Comment: :D yes. this is why i am asking on the 1st place - because the project is considerable big, and i dont wana waste time later and rewrite :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some years ago I tested some libraries (including Indy) and the more efficient, for my usage, was [ICS](http://www.overbyte.be/frame_index.html?redirTo=/products/ics.html). Which is a very good reputation Open Source library. However I can't compare the *stability* with other products.

Comment: seems this is like another alternative.